# Is "Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example" still current?

Tags: c++

I need to learn C++. Because I like the book's concept and I can already program in several other languages I thought ["Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) would be the best choice. However, the book is over 12 years old. Is it still a good idea to pick it up or would I be missing too many important new features of the language?

Comment: The language pretty much changed once in the last 12 years. C++98 is widely in use today. Once you've learned about that, C++11 changes aren't that hard to pick up.

Comment: It is due for an update, but its copyright is causing a bit of a delay (it was originally copyright AT&T, but then AT&T got broken up into several pieces, and right now nobody's sure who actually owns the copyright).

Comment: It's just a slight opinion. I generally prefer newer material, but I think my class used one from 2005 that is still perfectly valid, save C++11. I'm sure someone can do much better than that spurt.

Comment: I personally think , Accelerated C++ is the best book to gain good knowledge in C++

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It remains one of the best books around.  It's based on C++98, but C++03 is more bug fixes than anything else, and most programmers can't use anything more recent anyway.  As with most languages that have been around for awhile, recent evolutions can be thought of as either fine tuning, or additional features to handle new issues (like threading).

Answer (score 1):

I read some C++ books, and i recomend C++ Primer. 
The way the author teaches the language is very insterestig. 
Besides its a "heavy" book, you can learn more deeply the language and how to avoid errors.